# Is my solution build as a 32-bit or 64-bit application?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I have trouble connecting to an Oracle database, because the Oracle Client software is for 32-bit applications only. How do I see what my solution is build for and how do I change it?

I use Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: which language ... C/C++ or C# ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The target platform is defined in the properties of the project:

[image]

Here's a [blog post](http://erikej.blogspot.com/2008/01/x64-and-sql-compact.html) you might find useful.